# Comment posting validation on Android app

Tags: bug, comments, android-app

User could post comment on any question without entering anything in comment box. It made call on server and server responded with invalid length or error message.

Instead, it should validate text and its length on mobile-side first, then if it's OK, then it should initiate a call for posting it to the server.

Comment: Improved a very tiny bit since then: it now prevents posting empty comment... but still sends with 1 character. Probably there's a reason why they chose to do that.

Comment: @AndrewT. worth asking Brian in the chat, he's the android app guru now. :)